# Is $f\in L^1$ approximated (in the sense of $L^1$) by a sequence of continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

For arbitrary $f\in L^1$, is there exist a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ s.t. $\lim_n \|f-f_n\|_1=0$ ?

I think this statement is true.

Let $f\in L^1.$

Since $C_c$ is dense in $L^1$, there is $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset C_c $ s.t. $$\lim_n f_n=f \quad \mathrm{in} \ \ L^1,$$
i.e. $\lim_n \|f-f_n\|_1=0.$

Since $\{f_n\}\subset C_c$, each $f_n$ is continuous.

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: Sure, but this is basically the same statement as "$C_c$ is dense in $L^1$" (except weaker because you don't ask for compact support), which you seem to have assumed.

Comment: If $A\subset B\subset X,$ and $A$ is dense in $X$ then $B$ is dense in $X.$ In my opinion no proof is required.